# scanner gives the same value 2x instead of one

Tags: java, variables, input, scope

so I have this function:

When I use the code below I pass the sphere radius to the scanner, he identifies the 
double's and should pass them on to the toRound function.

```
    String outputDoubles = " double one: 190.234567 and double two: 370.03245 "; 

    Scanner doubles = new Scanner(outputDoubles);
    doubles.useDelimiter("[^\\p{Alnum},\\.-]");
    while(true) {
        double takeDouble;

        if (doubles.hasNextDouble()) {
            takeDouble = doubles.nextDouble(); // takedouble
            System.out.println(toRound(takeDouble));

        }

        if (doubles.hasNext()) {
            doubles.next();


        }
        else {
            break;
        }

    }
```

the toRound is here below:

```
static String toRound (double number) {
    double x = number; // nog fixen
    System.out.println(" \n");
    double y = number; 
    return "" + x + y;
}
```

the problem is that it returns not: 190.234567 but it returns: 190.234567190.234567190
so it returns it 2 times after eachother.

Is there a way to fix this, i have been trying different things for hours but cant make it work.

Answer (score 4):

`return "" + x + y;` will convert 'x' to String then append it, convert 'y' to String and then append, hence the doubled-up output.

You need to rewrite this expression `"" + (x + y)` so that it will evaluate your expression before converting it to a String.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying that, I have to return 2 different value's. So my return has to look like: return "variable 1: " + x + "/nvariable 2: " + y;